# Need tool to change Hard Disk unique ID

Tags: hard-drive, uniqueidentifier

There was a tool called PB Downforce that did something like this. It has been discontinued as it was buggy and stopped working for its purposes. So, is there any alternative? I have a licensed piece of software that is attached to the HD ID. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, diskpart will do it for you

> diskpart
>   select disk 0 (or whatever disk it is)
>   uniqueid disk ID=[SIGNATURE]

Comment: Note that Vista/Server2008 and newer reference the GUID to find the OS when booting; changing it on a boot drive may require changing it in the BCD too.

Answer (score 1):

Linux fdisk command does that. Use a live linux distro if you don`t have an installation.

While in fdisk, enter extra commands section with X, then you can change the Disk ID using the I command.